# How to type a function that transforms some properties of an input object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Does anyone know how one would typ a transform function where only part of the keys are known/relevant and one of the known keys are optional? E.g.

```
const transform = <T extends BaseAkpiDto>(akpiDTO: T) => {
  const { startDate, periodData, ...akpiBase } = akpiDTO;
  const withMoments = {
    ...akpiBase,
    startDate: moment.utc(startDate),
  };

  if (!periodData) {
    return withMoments;
  }

  return {
    ...withMoments,
    lineData: akpiDtoToLineData(withMoments.startDate, periodData),
  };
};

interface BaseAkpiDto {
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  periodData?: PeriodDto[];
}

const test: WithPeriodData = akpiDTOtoAkpiData({
  id: 1,
  name: 'my name',
  startDate: '2019',
  periodData: [] as PeriodDto[],
});

interface WithPeriodData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  startDate: Moment;
  lineData: Period[];
}
```

I'm unable to get the return type to include a lineData property if (and only if) there is a lineData property on the input :(

Typescript complains to my `test`variable with the following message:

> Property 'lineData' is missing in type 'Pick<{ id: number; name:
>   string; startDate: string; periodData: PeriodDto[];
>   }, "id" | "name"> & { startDate: Moment; endDate: Moment; }' but
>   required in type 'WithPeriodData'.

Comment: Can you remove all those unknown/moment types and add the invocation with the `test` variable, where that error happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `transform` has conditional behavior. Looking on the control flow it can return or object which contains `lineData` or not. Therefor you cannot assign the return which is a union `IHaveLineData` | `IDoNotHaveLineData` to `IHaveLineData` as the return is just wider type. Imagine you want to assign smth which is `string | number` to `number`, because of the same reason you can't.

To be sure you get the wanted structure you need to append additional control flow to ensure the type. So just:

```
// at this level test is infered as with or without lineData
const test= akpiDTOtoAkpiData({
  id: 1,
  name: 'my name',
  startDate: '2019',
  periodData: [] as PeriodDto[],
});

if ('lineData' in test) {
  // here test is precisely the type with lineData
}
```

Comment: I was hoping it could be solved with generics and conditional types that were added in 2.8, but it's probably not possible, like you say  :(